# Ubicación de rutas auth

Tags: laravel

Estoy buscando las rutas de

```
Auth::routes()
```

Estoy usando Laravel 7

Pero en el archivo

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php
```

Ya no esta el método `auth`

Agradecería si alguien puede compartir información al respecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Están en el paquete `laravel/ui` en el archivo [AuthRouteMethods.php](https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/2.x/src/AuthRouteMethods.php).

Si tienes instalado el paquete en tu proyecto:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

las encontrarás en:

```
/tu-proyecto/vendor/laravel/ui/src/AuthRouteMethods.php
```

El comando artisan [ui:auth](https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/2.x/src/AuthCommand.php)

```
php artisan ui:auth
```

generará las rutas de autenticación, un `HomeController`, vistas de autenticación y un archivo de layout `app.blade.php`.

Prueba el comando de ayuda:

```
php artisan ui --help
```

o

```
php artisan help ui
```

para ver más opciones.

O revisa la documentación: Laravel [Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication).

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: @GabrielZapata considera si la respuesta te ayudó la marques como aceptada

Answer (score 0):

En laravel 7 ya no está el método auth, ni funciona el make:auth
Te paso el link de como se da de alta auth en laravel 7 
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication
[https://documentacion-laravel.com/authentication.html#introducción](https://documentacion-laravel.com/authentication.html#introducci%C3%B3n) (en español)

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.